# Remove unnecessary histogram peaks from a histogram.

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, histogram

I am working on an object tracking problem. I have two histograms of an object in 
a consecutive frames. Lets say these histograms are computed at time instances `t-1` and `t`. Below is an example of these two histograms.

As can be seen from the first histogram (computed at time instant `t-1`), all the peaks/distributions of the histogram are concentrated near to intensity value 100. This basically represents an object. However, at time instant `t`, there appears some unnecessary peaks (around intensity value 75).

I want to remove these peaks from the second histogram, therefore, would like to ask if there exists some robust method to do this job. These unnecessary peaks exist in almost every frame, therefore, by using some simple thresholding would not help me.

What I am currently doing (Threshold method): I compute median and standard deviation from the histogram at`t-1` and threshold current histogram at `t`, by using a following formula:

`low_thresh = med(t-1) - alpha*std(t-1)`

`high_thresh = med(t-1) + alpha*std(t-1)`

`hist_without_unnecessary_peaks = low_thresh < current_hist(t) < high_thresh`

This `alpha` is a parameter which can be adjusted. This way, I propagate this thresholding throughout all the frames. But, I don't get the robust result. Would be glad if somebody can please help me. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a larger number of consecutive frames? If so, and the peaks that you wish to keep are consistent enough (which looks like they are) then you can take the median values across multiple frames.

So instead of computing the median for the entire histogram, do it for each individual intensity value with the previous frame and the next frame (or with more frames for more accuracy). Then use the median value as the new intensity value in the histogram. This will remove the outliers (i.e. the noise you're seeing in the second frame).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that might work. But, unfortunately, I can not have larger number of consecutive frames. Because its an object tracking problem. And, also, these peaks are not going to be stable. It seems to me thresholding (what I am doing currently) is the only option I left with.

Comment: I'd imagine you could step back one frame and still get seemingly real time results (depends on frame rate). Then if you work one frame behind the current one you can have three frames to access and allow for the median filter to do its magic.

Comment: Thanks again, yes it can work also. I explain you my exact problem: I have two stereo videos (Left and Right) and a depth video (obtained from them). Problem is to track an object in either of the video (or, call them frames) and I would like to improve a tracker's result by with using an additional information, which is depth frames. So, these histograms are actually computed from the object's depth values. Therefore, all the peaks that belong to the object are going to be shifted in a random way, depending on the object's motion. So, to use many frames can be risky in this case.

Comment: Biggest evil in thresholding process is a standard deviation value because if there are unnecessary peaks (outliers) in the histogram, this value change a lot. However, median is quite stable.

Comment: hmm... that changes things... All I can suggest at this point then is to use as much knowledge as you have in the algorithm, such as if the object will be consistent in anything (depth?) then use that as a template to match on. The more you can get away from thresholds the better, imo. Perhaps use something more probabilistic or like a grab cut approach?

Answer (score 1):

Sanchit, I had to solve this issue when I was handling with RGBD cameras as well.

The solution:

(A) Apply the following contrast function on your histogram:
[image: Contrast Function]

where C(i,n) is the new histogram at index `i` (of the old histogram) and `n` is a parameter that you choose (and tune) - Note that this results in a new histogram, n is just a parameter

(B) Find all local maxima/minima points on your histogram and choose the maximal one.
There is plenty of maxima/minima finding Matlab code on the web so you will not have a problem.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try clustering the data and keeping only the cluster with the most members. This could be done by finding the peaks (this might be tricky depending on how much noise you have) in the histogram and using that as the k value in [kmeans](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html).